# Validar busqueda y volver atras en un error javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un catálogo de compra-venta de camisetas de futbol y en la parte de las compras quiero que el usuario ingrese la camiseta deseada y la imprima en la consola con sus datos. El problema es que si al buscar el item no se encuentra en la lista con los productos, como hago para volver a la busqueda y que se imprima en la consola. Aquí está el codigo:

```
function buscarPorEquipo(array){
    let equipoBuscado = prompt("Ingrese el equipo del que desea buscar una camiseta")

    let equipoEncontrado = perchero.find(
        club=> club.equipo.toLowerCase() == equipoBuscado.toLowerCase())

    if(equipoEncontrado == undefined){
        console.log(`La camiseta de ${equipoBuscado} aun no se encuentra en nuestro catalogo`)
        prompt("Ingrese nuevamente el equipo a buscar")

    }else{
        console.log(equipoEncontrado)
        alert(`Elegiste la camiseta de ${equipoBuscado}`)
    }
}
```

Aclaración: Perchero es una lista que contiene los distintos equipos de los cuales tenemos camisetas (cada uno es un objeto con distintos elementos, el importante aquí es el de equipo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```js
function buscarPorEquipo(){
    let equipoBuscado = prompt("Ingrese el equipo del que desea buscar una camiseta")

    let equipoEncontrado = perchero.find(
        club=> club.equipo.toLowerCase() == equipoBuscado.toLowerCase())

    if(equipoEncontrado == undefined){
        console.log(`La camiseta de ${equipoBuscado} aun no se encuentra en nuestro catalogo`)
        alert("No encontrado. Ingrese nuevamente el equipo a buscar")
        buscarPorEquipo()

    }else{
        console.log(equipoEncontrado)
        alert(`Elegiste la camiseta de ${equipoBuscado}`)
    }
}
var perchero = [
  {equipo: "Madrid"},
  {equipo: "Sevilla"}
]
buscarPorEquipo()
```

### Cambios aplicados:

1. Se ha eliminado el parámetro `array` de la función `buscarPorEquipo` pues no se usaba internamente
2. Se ha cambiado este prompt:

```
prompt("Ingrese nuevamente el equipo a buscar")
```

por un alert():

```
alert("No encontrado. Ingrese nuevamente el equipo a buscar")
```

para advertir al usuario que no existe el equipo que ha puesto.

3. Después de la advertencia volvemos a preguntale que equipo quiere volviendo a llamar a la misma función para repetir el proceso de nuevo, a ver si esta vez pone uno correcto:

```
buscarPorEquipo()
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente, no sé cómo no me di cuenta antes. Muchas gracias